# php cookie is set for whole domain even if it is set for sub directory

Tags: php, cookies

I am setting php cookie for sub directory but the cookie is visible in other sub directories as well. I could not find what's going wrong.

```
setcookie("sessionEmail", $_POST['email'], time()+36000, "mywebsite.com/dir1");
```

So i expect the cookie should be available only in `mywebsite.com/dir1;`
but it is also available in `mywebsite.com/dir2`

```
isset($_COOKIE['sessionEmail']) --> is coming as TRUE in dir2 folder
```

I tried even after clearing cookies , still same issue : `setcookie("sessionEmail", "", time()-3600);`

can you please help me here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path parameter does *not* take a URL. It takes a path only. (The domain is the next parameter)

```
setcookie("sessionEmail", $_POST['email'], time()+36000, "/dir1");
```

or

```
setcookie("sessionEmail", $_POST['email'], time()+36000, "/dir1", "mywebsite.com");
```

Comment: while unsetting `setcookie("sessionEmail", "", time()-3600);` is enough to clear all cookies including sub directory ?

Comment: what if the subfolder does not exist ? will the cookie be set to whole domain or it will not be set at all ?

Comment: It will be set, it just won't ever be used.